# Open Menu links in new browser window

Tags: javascript

I have created various menus, via the menu structure->menu page in Drupal for various pages in my site.  I want to have some, if not all, of these menu links to open in a new page. You can not add `target="_blank"` to the path in the menu screen and I don't want to add a new module right now.

**I am trying this:**

```
Drupal.behaviors.externalMenu = function (context) {
  if (jQuery().attr) {
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.page-node-166 a', context).attr('target', '_blank');
});
}}
```

My Steps: created a new js file, added the above code, went into my themes .info file, referenced this js file in the scripts section, refreshed, a few times, nothing works.  Links still open in current window.

What should be happening in this code snippet is, find this class[page-node-166], which is the page, then for any link on that page, open it in new window.  My first time attempting this so I don't know if I am missing a step.

How can I have menu links open in new window in drupal 7?

=====================

Update: [image]

Comment: Remove context.  See my update below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really need a drupal behavior to do this.  Instead just simple do this:

```
;(function($){
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.page-node-166 a').attr('target', '_blank');
  });
})(jQuery);
```

or

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery('.page-node-166 a').attr('target', '_blank');
});
```

By default drupal uses [jQuery.noConflict()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/) so that it does not interfere with the $ that may be used from other libraries.

Comment: Hi Chad - thanks for the quick reply.  I tried both solutions, but get the same error.  note image above.  I have double check, the class is spelled and referenced correctly.  any ideas?